# JQuery: table parser and CSS change

Tags: jquery, uitableview

I have a table in the following format:

```
<table id="searchResultTable">
    <tr>
        <th>List</th>
    </tr>

    <tr onMouseOver="activeTr(this)"
        onMouseOut="inactiveTr(this)" onClick="showDetails(TODO)">
        <td><a href="javascript: void(0)">AAA</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr onMouseOver="activeTr(this)"
        onMouseOut="inactiveTr(this)" onClick="showDetails(TODO)">
        <td><a href="javascript: void(0)">BBB</a></td>
    </tr>
</table
```

The following CSS:

```
table#searchResultTable td {
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ECD7C2;
}
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And the following JS functions:

```
function activeTr( row ) {
    row.bgColor='#ECD7C2';
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
}

function inactiveTr( row ) {
    row.bgColor='transparent';
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
}
```

Everything works fine so far. But now I'm trying to **replace the class for selected row to .bold and**  have to **remove the same class from all other unselected rows** - that's what `showDetails(TODO)` should do. I made several attempts (including based on the content as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651766/how-to-set-the-row-class-of-a-table-based-on-cell-content-using-jquery)), but couldn't get it to work.

Please point me in the right direction (JQuery would be great ;). Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
Table (with head and body):

```
<table id="searchResultTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
                <th>List</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
                <td><a href="javascript: void(0)">AAA</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
                <td><a href="javascript: void(0)">BBB</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

add a new css class:

```
.active{
    background-color: #fab;
}
```

and some jquery magic:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var activeRow;
        $(function() {
            $("#searchResultTable tbody tr").hover(function() {
                this.bgColor = '#ECD7C2';
                document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            }, function() {
                this.bgColor = 'transparent';
                document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
            }).
            click(function() {
                $(activeRow).removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
                activeRow = this;
            });
        });



    </script>
```

Notice that in this way your html is not poluted with Javascript code, good separation of view and logic.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick with minor adaptations!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are talking about a jquery table hover plugin. In which case you might try looking at http://p.sohei.org/stuff/jquery/tablehover/demo/demo.html