# JQuery: how to select parent table for parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JS function which parses through a table:

```
// id contains a message id, activeRow is "this" from onClick on tr
function doSomething ( id, activeRow ) {
    // AJAX calling using id as parameter
    $("#searchResultTable > tbody > tr").each(function(index) {
        $(this).removeClass("bold");
    });
}
```

This works perfectly fine (thanks to Ariel @ [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379157/jquery-table-parser-and-css-change/1379498#1379498)), but I was thinking that there should be another possibility, like:

```
var table = $(activeRow).parent();
$("tbody > tr", table).each(function(index) {
    // .. do something
});
// The above clearly doesn't work, but should document what I'm looking for.
```

This would allow the usage of the same table ID while the function would work on each of them separately.

Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, you would want to use a class on the table

```
$("table.className tbody tr").each(function() {
    // .. do something
});
```

Answer (score 5):

jQuery's [parents()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parents) method makes getting the parent table a snap:

```
$(activeRow).parents('table')[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
$(activeRow).siblings().andSelf().removeClass("bold")
```

That'll take the `<tr>` in `activeRow`, grab its sibling `<tr>`s too, and remove the `"bold"` class from all of them.

Answer (score 3):

It may be better to use `closest` as follows:

```
$(activeRow).closest('table')[0];
```

From here: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

> closest: Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector.
>
> parents: Travels up the DOM tree to the document's root element, adding each ancestor element to a temporary collection; it then filters that collection based on a selector if one is supplied.

In this scenario it may well be that `parents` gets the top most table where there are more than one in the DOM tree, where as `closest` gets the one you are actually trying to work on.

Comment: I know that this answer was rather late, however I've come across this answer on a number of google searches so figured it was worth contributing.